Diagnosing Current Transformer Failures By Looking At Excitation Curve
This is sort of a general question to indulge my curiosity.
I am a design engineer for a company that manufactures instrument transformers. Every now and then we get some units that fail out in the field and the customers will send us test results from either an Omicron CT analyzer or a Vanguard EZCT tester. The former uses frequency response to calculate ratio errors and produces excitation curve values, the latter actually applies voltage and produces excitation curve values.
Most of the time these testers won't even allow you to complete the test if an open circuit or short circuit is detected, but sometimes they will, and our customers will send us these test files so we can plot the curves against our calculated design values.
By plotting against our design curves, we can tell that SOMETHING is wrong, but can't produce a specific diagnosis as to what caused the failure. I guess my question is how can you tell what type of failure a CT is having based on the tested excitation curve values? Will a shorted CT or an open circuited CT have distinctive curve shapes? If so, what would those look like and can someone explain how each type of failure produces its unique curve shape?

Who would know better then design engineer of said devices.. hopefully

@ursusd8 What a helpful comment. As a design engineer I know how the curves are calculated, how to reverse engineer a CT from an excitation curve, how to calculate ratio error from the curves, I can tell if a CT was built with a larger/smaller core than was intended from the curves, I can tell why a CT fails a ratio test from the curves. What I don't know, because of lack of documentation and only having 2 years of experience, is what specific shapes the curves will have during either of those two failure modes. If you don't have an answer then why comment at all? This isn't Reddit...
